# WordPress 2.8.6 foobars my theme options with escape slashes

Tags: wordpress

I've just upgraded a blog to WordPress 2.8.6 and found they are escaping quotes differently from 2.8.5

I've got a theme options panel that allows the user to input their img tags into a text area.

However, when the options are saved, WP is adding escape slashes to the double quotes it finds in the text area.

Example:

`<img src="somefile.jpg" />`

becomes

`<img src=\"somefile.jpg\" />`

And this causes the image to fail to load

Also, on every save of my theme options, the backslashes are doubling growing in number!!!

```
function mytheme_add_admin() {

global $themename, $shortname, $options;

if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {

if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

  foreach ($options as $value) {
    update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); 
  }

  foreach ($options as $value) {
    if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) { 
      update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); 
    } else { 
      delete_option( $value['id'] ); 
    } 
  }

  header("Location: themes.php?page=functions.php&saved=true");
  die;

} else if( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

  foreach ($options as $value) {
     delete_option( $value['id'] ); 
  }

 header("Location: themes.php?page=functions.php&reset=true");
 die;

}
```

Comment: Did anything else change? Hosts? PHP configuration? Sure sounds like a case of the magic quotes.

Comment: Magic Quotes? Not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?
No change in hosts. Only change was some code enhancements to the theme and upgrade to WP 2.8.6

Same code on 2.8.5 works fine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress always performs `magic_quotes_gpc` for backwards compat reasons. When dealing with GPC data, you must run `stripslashes()` on the data to get it in its raw form.

Comment: thanks mark. that's what I was looking for. I've used stripslashes in my functions.php file to resolve it.